# How to make JComboBox appear in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox that used to appear in the JFrame and now it doesn't...Not sure why but I think it might have to do with JPanels and/or Containers. I want there to be a JComboBox with the different clothing types in it. The JFrame appears without the JComboBox, which is weird.
Here is my code:

```
 public void init() {
    JComboBox dropDown = new JComboBox(description);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        cont.add(t);
        cont.add(c);

    final JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
     c.addItem(description[count++]);
      t.setEditable(false);
    }//end of for
      c.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          if (count < description.length){
            c.addItem(description[count++]);
          }//end of if
            selected = " "+((JComboBox) evt.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
}//end of method
};//end of listener
}//end of method
```

Comment: @Paul `frame.setConentPane(c)`...

Comment: You should use `frame.add(c)` instead of `setContentPane`...that's kind of heavy handed...

Comment: You code is kind of hard to read, it "looks" like you're adding the combo box from instead the `ActionListener`....?

Comment: This is a very stange code snippet, like a jigsaw puzzle with too many pieces missing to quite see what the picture is.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried the .add and it doesn't show...

Comment: It's really impossible to know exactly what the problem is. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have applied ";" after your loop. That is a great mistake.
I've read your code and done some changes.
Have a look at this.
This code shows the JComboBox on the screen.

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class ans
{
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
String description[]={
"Hello","Bye","Java","Python","Fortran","Pascal"
};
int count=0;


JComboBox c=new JComboBox();
public void init() {
    final JPanel pan = new JPanel();
pan.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        c.addItem(description[count++]);
        c.setEditable(false);
        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //Do Something
                }//end of if

    // ... ? ...
}});
    frame.setContentPane(c);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
}
public static void main(String arg[])
{
ans a=new ans();
a.init();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't see all the important parts of your code but one likely problem is the `;` after the `for` loop.

`for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++);
        c.addItem(description[count++]);`

Will only add an item of count 0.